# How do I point 2 godaddy domains to my vps.net server?

Tags: domain-name-system, domain

I don't understand how this works.

So I have 2 domains at godaddy. I set both there dns to `dns1.vps.net` and `dns2.vps.net`

I have a vps setup at vps.net. I can SSH to this server using the IP address for my vps. I setup apache. I can now reach my server in a browser via `http://server-ip`

But how do the domains know which server at vps.net to point to?

There has to be another step? Otherwise they would point to every server on vps.net.

How do I tell the domains to point to this particular server?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You appear to lack a fundamental understanding of how DNS works.  I would suggest speaking to someone at GoDaddy and having them host your DNS and help you with getting it set up properly using their web-based DNS control panel.

I would also suggest investing the time and (minimal) money in picking up a copy of [DNS & BIND](http://oreilly.com/catalog/9780596100575) (physical or e-book) and reading through it before attempting to do anything involving DNS.

Answer (score 3):

Someone has to host DNS for you. If your VPS come with that, find our from them the address of the Name Servers (usually something like ns1.example.com and ns2.example.com). If you don't have anybody to host DNS, you'll need to find someone (GoDaddy has plans you can buy too).

In your domain name manager on GoDaddy change the nameservers for the domain(s) to match what you got from the DNS host.

Now setup DNS with the DNS host. Usually they make this really easy; but they should have help either way. You need for DNS to point to the VPS server's IP addresses.

Comment: I agree with what you said. To make this a bit concrete for John: I would use godaddy.net to point an A record at your server. -----GoDaddy hosts your dns, and godaddy's dns is set to point an A record to your server. This is a link to GoDaddy's instructions. http://help.godaddy.com/article/680#arecs

Comment: The `dns1.vps.net` and `dns2.vps.net` were the name servers. So once I st them on the godaddy side, I then had to go to `vps.net/domains` to add those domains to my server.